# SQL query from Lynda.com

Tags: sql

I have a question about two queries. Will these two queries give the same result? I am trying to find the average salary by department:

```
Select s1.department, avg(s1.salary)
From 
(Select department, salary
From staff
Where salary > 100000) s1
Group by s1.department
```

vs

```
select department, avg(salary) as avg_salary
from staff
where salary > 100000
group by department
```

Comment: what is the RDBMS u r using? mysql, sql-server? not clear what u r asking. you can run queries and see if their results are equal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it gives the same amounts back. 
the bottom query gets data from a sub select which gets its data from the table, whereas the top query gets it straight from the table itself.

There are no additional filters in there. So the result will be the same.

you can test it out however, don't take my word for it.